# Using jQuery mobile, want to disable navigation completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

We would like to use jquery mobile for all aspects of our site, but disable the page transitions completely, as we need to handle navigation on our own. So far, we have added the following to no avail:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
                $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
            });
```

Our main problem is, all the "href" attribute values are being replaced with a hash tag (just a single #) and are losing our original href values, causing our navigation to obviously fail.

How can I prevent jQuery mobile from replacing my href attributes entirely? Thanks.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: I tried using rel="external", $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false, etc. It still replaces my href with #. I even tried using target="_blank".

Comment: Perhaps because you are running the settings inside of an init handler? Why not run them immediately? You need it to change the flags before jQuery mobile runs but after it has been loaded. As stated in the linked document.

Comment: I moved the init to be before JQM and after JQ. It still changes my urls to be #. http://i.imgur.com/8Cbhx.jpg

Comment: BTW, this all works just fine in a normal web browser using a mobile user agent. It breaks in my Ripple emulator and on my android (by break, i mean replaces with #).

Comment: "I moved the init to be before JQM" nonono, not _before_ JQM itself, just make sure it runs after the JQM script is loaded but before the document is ready and JQM actually runs. If that doesn't help then it's not the problem you're having.

Comment: @TheZ You bind to `mobileinit` after jQuery Core loads and before jQuery Mobile loads. Docs here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html. You need to bind to the `mobileinit` event before jQuery Mobile runs because by the time it's done running, the `mobileinit` event has already fired.

Comment: @Jasper Ahhhh okay, that makes more sense. Maybe I just didn't get it the way he was explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure where you got the `ajaxLinksEnabled` and the `ajaxFormsEnabled` options but they aren't listed on the "Configuring Default" documentation page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html. Try using the above option, `ajaxEnabled`.

Comment: Thank you, but still having the issue. Here are screenshots of my updated script as well as what I'm seeing in an emulator (and my phone). Code: http://i.imgur.com/33LxW.jpg, emulator: http://i.imgur.com/KV1KF.jpg. The highlighted "Accounts" link should point to a relative url, but still has the # after running.

EDIT: changed to bind, but "on" still does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! It turned out that I needed to set linkBindingEnabled to be false. Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
                // Reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html
                $.extend($.mobile, {
                    linkBindingEnabled: false,
                    ajaxEnabled: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```